# Unallow a Circle instance to accept a Point3D as center

Tags: oop, inheritance, dry

I would like to submit a OOP problem. Maybe it has been solved elsewhere, but I wasn't able to find it...

Imagine something like this (Python-like pseudo-code)

```
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

    # Some methods here    

class Point3D(Point):
    z: int

class Circle:
    center: Point
    radius: int

    # Some methods here

class Sphere(Circle):
    center: Point3D
```

In a statically typed language - unless I make a mistake - a `Point3D` instance will pass as a `center` attribute for `Circle`, since it inherits from `Point`, which has to be unallowed, because it would turn into a `Sphere`-like.

How can we achieve that without losing methods factorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP) states that replacing an instance of a base classe with an instance of a derived class shall always work. This is a core feature of OOP, not an issue.

The issue is in you model -- let's consider what the relationship between a 2D point and a 3D point is. Having `Point3D` inherit from `Point2D` states that a `Point3D` *is a* `Point2D`, that is, all `Point3D`'s are also `Point2D`'s.

But this does not actually fit what you're modeling! In math, only 3D points from the 2D plane (the ones with `z == 0`) are actually 2D points. This discrepancy is the source of that loophole that might turn your `Circle` into a sphere.

The OOP model for this could actually be the opposite: all 2D points *are* 3D points, with `z == 0`. Thus `Point2D` inheriting from `Point3D` would kind of make sense. It would, however, open up a new set of problems with mutability: if you are able to access a `Point2D` as a `Point3D` and modify it, then you can set its `z` coordinate to be non-zero, and end up with an inconsistent `Point2D` that is not actually 2D anymore. LSP is broken again.

---

It is tempting to represent the relationship between a 2D and a 3D point in OOP in either direction:

- A 3D point contains one more coordinate that a 2D point doesn't use, thus it should be the derived class

... or...

- Mathematically, a 2D points is also a 3D point, so *it* should be the derived class

... but the bottom line is simply that *neither class can inherit from the other one*, because the LSP is broken either way. Keep them as separate classes, apples with apples and `Circle`s with `Point2D`s, and use some other language features if you need to factor common code between points -- generic programming, for example.

Comment: Very clear, thank you for the explanation! But I was thinking about using an abstract super class in order to [`dry`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)... (It's now even possible in python with `ABC`s a.k.a. Abstract Base Classes) The abstract class can't be instanciate, `Point2D` and `Point3D` aren't inheriting one from another, so the LSP is respected. Your opinion?

Comment: Yes, that would be valid, as long as you take care to put in the base class only stuff that is actually common to both types of points.